# Linux read form serial port - fork workaround & how to change EOL?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to send data via serial port and receive the response. Currently I'm looping the interface physically to emulate the device.

I have to change the EOL to be CR not LF. If I try and use `\xD` instead of `\xA` nothing happens:

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 eol ^M eol2 ^M eof ^M
# cat /dev/ttyUSB0 &
[1] 7891
# echo -ne "foo\xD"
# echo -ne "foo\xA"
foo
```

Thank you for your help!

(edited: part about fork workaround moved to separate topic).

Comment: You should split this up into two separate questions. You can use the Edit link below the question to adjust the title and remove the content not related to the main question. Please read in the StackOverflow help center about how to ask questions and to acquaint yourself with the site philosophy. The SO concept differs from that of "forums"

Comment: Do you plan to do the from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to change the EOL:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello World\x0d"'
```

Shell version

```
echo -en "foo\015">r.txt
xxd r.txt
0000000: 666f 6f0d                                foo.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without perl?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the same as # echo -ne `foo\xD` as i wrote in my question. The problem is serial interface doesn't respond to the `\xD` even if i do:
`# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 eol ^M eol2 ^M eof ^M`

Comment: flood all chars and check what your USB device responses: perl -e 'print chr($_) for 1..255'